# Find out which app created a file?

Tags: macos, mac

I keep seeing a number of text files being created in a particular folder on my mac. I've a feeling that they are being created by a widget I downloaded, however I thought I'd removed the widget months ago.

They're simple text files with a ".torrent" extension and are created in my `Movies` directory. It looks as though something "listening" to torrent trackers for release of Public Domain programs and automatically creating the torrent files for them ready to be picked up by a torrent app.

Is it possible to find out what application created a file? I'd like to track down which app it is so I can kill it for good - if there are other ways to find it I'd appreciate comments!

**Edit:**

Thanks to a reply I tried out `fseventer`. I deleted the files, started recording, then went about doing various things. After about 30mins the files returned without any action from me, so I stopped fseventer and reviewed the log. It had only recorded things I had done manually, nothing automated.

So, any other ideas? This is really starting to annoy me as they never go away (for long)!

Comment: What are the files named, where are they being created and what's in them?

Comment: Odd, I think `fseventer` basically uses the same information that Time Machine uses, so it should notice *any* file that's created, not just those resulting from manual interaction. But I might be wrong here...

Comment: **Related for Windows vistors:** http://superuser.com/questions/348881/find-out-which-program-creates-a-file-folder-in-my-c-drive

Answer (score 4):

Check out [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start). It's basically FileMon for Mac.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work; it seemed to only show what applications I'd opened manually during the recording process. Updated the question with details.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [`sudo opensnoop`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html), from the command line, for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/) helped me track down that it was [TVShows](http://tvshows.sourceforge.net) grabbing the torrent files. Disabling the item has stopped the torrent files from being created.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the files, reboot your mac and then run fseventer for a while, overnight would be best, without you using the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [Miro](http://getmiro.com)? Sounds like something it would do, to me.