# Mac: Why do I keep getting an Applications folder in my home folder, and how do I stop it?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I'm on 10.6.2, all patched up and pretty. I am an admin user. I put all my applications in `/Applications`.

Yet, every now and then an empty `~/Applications` folder pops up. (Well, not strictly empty, it has a `.localized` file.)

Why why why?

Please make it stop.

Comment: Why not go with the friendly suggestion and start putting your apps in ~/Applications ? That's what I do.

Comment: I'm guessing a specific application is putting it there. Can you gather any more information from the `.localized` file or anything?

Comment: Man, Mac users have to suffer this annoyance too? It's *my* filesystem, stupid applications, *I'll* decide whether I want to call the folder I put production work in “My Videos” (tip: no).

Comment: Do you have CrossOver installed?
When I install some window apps with CrossOver it puts them in ~/Applications

Comment: .localized is standard in system folders. They names appear localized in the Finder if you use another language. (Double annoying, that)

Comment: @bobince Some applications like to party in your ~/Documents folder. Microsoft ones especially.

Comment: @Philippe Mongeau: No CrossOver.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd try is emptying ~/Applications completely by deleting and re-creating the folder, then attaching a folder action to it that pops an alert whenever something is added to it (there's one already in /Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/). That, and perhaps checking the Console when an item is added (/Applications/Utilities/Console), should tell you whodunnit.

Comment: Nice idea! Care to add an answer about the folder action to "Find out which app created a file?" at http://superuser.com/questions/69682/find-out-which-app-created-a-file as well?

Comment: Sounds good, but nothing ever gets added to ~/Applications, so what I should do instead is remove it, and add the Folder Action to my home folder, waiting for the Applications folder to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Adobe Air on your computer? If you have that is most likely the cause of the newly created folder.

Comment: I don't think so. But Adobe is sneaky. Do they force it on you with CS? What traces of it can I look for? I might have run an Air-based application. (And immediately deleted it because of TEH UGLY, but I digress.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is created quite often, then maybe [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) can help finding what creates it?

(See also [Find out which app created a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/69682/find-out-which-app-created-a-file) for other hints, like [`sudo opensnoop`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html))